# How to restrict object fields in Typescript using Type parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeguards

I am using Typescript. I want to create an Object like this,

```
const statusMessageMap = {
  'ENABLE': 'This is enable',
  'DISABLE': 'This is disable',
}
```

And I want to restrict fields of this object. I can easily do it like this...

```
interface Status = {
  ENABLE: string;
  DISABLE: string;
}

const statusMessageMap: Status = {
  'ENABLE': 'This is enable',
  'DISABLE': 'This is disable',
}
```

But I already have a type defined before and I want to keep it.

```
type OldStatus = 'ENABLED' | 'DISABLE'
```

But it is not working like this...

```
//this is not working
const statusMessageMap: OldStatus = {
  'ENABLE': 'This is enable',
  'DISABLE': 'This is disable',
}
```

I don't want to keep both ***Status*** and ***OldStatus*** because, it will make me to update in two places if I want to add a new status.

I want to keep my ***OldStatus*** type and want to use it to restrict type of the object. How can I do it? Is it possible to create a new interface extending the ***OldStatus*** type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message map type should be `{ [key in OldStatus]: string }` using `OldStatus`:

```
type OldStatus = 'ENABLE' | 'DISABLE'

const statusMessageMap: { [key in OldStatus]: string } = {
  'ENABLE': 'This is enable',
  'DISABLE': 'This is disable',
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gNgEwMrAIbAK4GcoF4oDkAogHICCAQgDJEFQA+hAIgJJKU0EBQXAxgPYA7LMCgj02ALIQsWVAHMIk1GABcUAN5QA2gGsIIKAEtBsRCglYAuupEAnE-KgBfPJq5RCpDrXUEAKgAWRjghUBCCqABGcBAEADQezGw+BH5BYWEIIdGxCVzOQA)